# jquery .closest() return undefined

Tags: jquery

I dont know, where is the mistakes. Anyone know?

```
<div class="col">
 <input type="hidden" value="12" id="number">
  <button class="btn-green btn-big" id="confirm" style="width: 146px;margin-top:6px;">
   <i class="spritemedium pr10 mr5" style="border-right: 1px solid #fff"></i>
   Pesan
  </button>
</div>  

<script>
$("#confirm").click(function ()
{
    var a = $(this).closest("#number").val();
    alert(a);
}
</script>
```

when button `confirm` clicked, it return undefined. I use `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>` is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

**[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** will traverse up the DOM tree and match the closest ancestor, in your case `#number` input is the immediate previous sibling of `#confirm` button, so you need to use **[.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)** instead:

```
var a = $(this).prev().val();
```

However, `id` must be unique, you can simply use:

```
var a = $("#number").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use .closest() here, it finds the control in its parent. You should use prev() here:

```
  <script>
 $("#confirm").click(function ()
 {
 var a = $(this).prev("input#number").val();
 alert(a);
 }
</script>
```